# Use sass with windows powershell to save scss to css that's in a different directory

Tags: css, powershell, sass

I've been using sass a little and have been placing the .scss file in the same directory as the .css file and using windows powershell with the following command to compile: `sass --watch --style expanded screen.scss:style.css`.

It's been working fine, and without having to move to a package manager I was wondering if I'd be able to move my .scss file into another directory and somehow use the same command line to compile; I am trying to take advantage of using partials and want to have a dedicated directory (/sass/) with all my .scss files.

So is there a way to do something like `sass --watch --expanded screen.scss:../style.css` to somehow tell the powershell to go back one directory and find the style.css file?

Comment: Sass compile commands can be relative paths, sure. Unless there's some limitation caused by Windows Powershell, I don't know any reason why this wouldn't work. I compile to different directories all the time.

Comment: @cimmanon yes, that didn't work.

Comment: @jameson what would be the correct syntax? My style.css file is in the root of my child folder and my scss files are all in a /sass/ folder.

Comment: That should be the correct syntax, though watching a single file like that will only watch changes to *that* file.  It won't watch changes to your partials.  You have to watch the entire directory for that.

Comment: @cimmanon is right, you want to watch the whole folder, so it would be more like this: `sass --watch --expanded scss:../css`

Comment: @jameson Okay. Though when I do `sass --watch --style expanded sass:../style.css` I get an error that says `no such file or directory - sass`

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at your file structure, but you'll need to make sure you put all your .scss files in a folder called 'sass' or 'scss' or whatever, and then update that first path to point to it.

Comment: @jameson when you say "update the first path to point to it", what exactly do you mean? My style.css is in the root of the child folder; my screen.scss files, as well as all my partial.scss files are in a folder called `sass`. I tried using the previous cmd and still got that error. To me that line reads "save everything in the sass folder and compile it by going back one folder (into the root) and saving it to the style.css file". Or am I missing something?

Comment: So if the "sass" folder is on the same level as the "css" folder, it'd be `sass --watch --expanded ../scss:../css`, I think. But just play with the path until you find it. Might be helpful to start from a root folder, like `public/sass` or `/public/sass`.

Comment: @jameson does it matter I am editing these files from my FTP? In terms of file paths? When the .scss and .css files were in the root it worked fine, but moving them into folders is the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be wrong. I'm looking at a site of mine where the 'sass' and 'css' folders are at root, and the compile command I use for that is `sass --watch sass:css`. That works fine.

Comment: @jameson Are you doing this in your FTP? I'm accessing windows powershell through sublime text 2. What file are you on when you access powershell?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using powershell - maybe the issue you're having is related to how it handles path names or something.